# iOS FacebookSDK image share

Tags: ios, facebook

I am using the following code to upload an image from my iOS to Facebook.

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setObject:@"MY TEST MSG..." forKey:@"message"];
[params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.editImageView.image) forKey:@"picture"];


[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"uploaded");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Graph API Error: %@", [error description]);
        }
}];
```

My app got stuck for couple of minutes and show the error message.
Can any one please help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];
UIImage *picture = FilterImage;
FbGraphFile *graph_file = [[FbGraphFile alloc] initWithImage:picture];
[variables setObject:graph_file forKey:@"file"];
[variables setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello testin"] forKey:@"message"];
[fbGraph doGraphPost:@"me/photos" withPostVars:variables];
NSLog(@"Now log into Facebook and look at your profile & photo albums...");
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you please tell me which Facebook package should I import for FbGraphFile?

Comment: Latest facebook package.

Comment: I am using the SDK released on this last Sept. But I can't understand Which file to import? (like, #import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h> )

Comment: you need to add FBSDKCoreKit.framework ,FBSDKLoginKit.framework and FBSDKShareKit

Comment: Kindly  tick my answer